# cURL and file_get_contents are not working with IMDb videoplayer links

Tags: php, web-scraping

I trying to scrape the trailer source out of IMDb video link.

I tried to use file_get_contents(); but i end up with [ HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] error and cURL gives me 302 found the document has moved here instead of the page source

i am trying get the full source from a given url
so for example

```
function url_get_contents($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$url = "https://www.imdb.com/videoplayer/vi639154713?playlistId=tt6418918&ref_=tt_ov_vi";
$source = file_get_contents(urlencode($url));
//ends up with[ HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] or
//failed to open stream: No such file or directory in case of using urlencode
$source = url_get_contents($url);
//ends up with 302 Document has moved here .. probably missing the right options for curl
//--------//
//some scraping done with strpos and substr targeting the only video tag in the page "not the main problem"
echo $videoSourceLink;

//expected output for the previous url in the next comment---->
//https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi639154713/1434659607842-pgv4ql-1547571245800.mp4?Expires=1555441981&Signature=gCtvwysi4WEvNbDuxBUCU75ABkTAprFhyt-P16D8o92fXFe~tWsYinU66VSMQT2f157d9f5dwkT3-vJcgT8aiJowsABIpkBd~oZIzJenM2e3W4wovZ8Z3l7NEmcGXjqhLpJ7eP2yu8JYZpgpSWeCIe7V5RiMhwIIPcKzlB3x6iWxy8rMRpaJZ8Vr7ZyadsIExbmCRK5OTFV4hZ2MbTMEtd-tRPKxthpzqaSQ18gvaBVH900SO76lqNWXRD-DnnSHjYsAnOVePfEqdff5o3PiaUpuGLEQbkNKlsgSPfYNHI74k6eOEGUehUjuzNCggb8LqActG7gPceOf4fD3xz4Vqg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA
```

## Update 1:

now when i use url_get_contents function that is using cURL it gives this response
[image]

Comment: What is this `get_full_page_source` function?

Comment: the function that should be the answer to get the full page source

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you were showing us what you had tried. For example, showing us the cURL code you used might lead people to point out where you used an incorrect parameter.

Comment: Edited, Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What does `url_get_contents` look like? It's not a standard PHP function. Also note that 302 is not an *error*, it's a redirect; what URL is it redirecting you to?

Comment: Also assuming that by `get_file_contents` you meant `file_get_contents`. Did you try `urlencode`-ing the URL, as suggested on the man page for that function?

Comment: using urlencode wont help it gives me failed to open stream: No such file or directory. url_get_content() is a function that is using curl function and yes get_file_contents is mistyped it should be file_get_contents()

Comment: Again, without seeing the contents of `url_get_contents`, it's hard to help.

Comment: actually it is edited time ago .. sorry for not calling that

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that.

Comment: Your function is missing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`, but even with that it doesn't work for me either. Might be that IMDB is using cookies or other trickery?

Comment: surely they are guarding the the source with something .. to not scrape the video source out of the page